# Updating meeting recipient calendar through service account

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, google-api-java-client

Can my app update google calendar recipient meeting, if the recipient has given access to the service account of the App? When I try to do that, I get this message:

```
Exception thrown: 403 Forbidden
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<email_account>/events
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "calendar",
      "message": "You need to have writer access to this calendar.",
      "reason": "requiredAccessLevel"
    }
  ],
  "message": "You need to have writer access to this calendar."
}
```

I need to have the recipient's calendar provide 'Make changes to events' rights to my google cloud console's email under which the web app is registered and only then my app is able to create meeting with that recipient.

There is an issue with this approach - which is, if recipient provides such an access to the username under which the app is registered, that username can now see all events of recipient's calendar. This may not what recipient wants.

This makes me wonder, why not let the owner of the web app's service account schedule meetings with recipients, with such access to that service account and since service account cannot login, there is no such drawback - like described above?

[Edit: Adding minimal reproducible example, as requested]

I am authorizing my API call as described in [this example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java).

```
//Define scope, credentials path and token path
        private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
        private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "/Users/<username>/<workspace_name>/<project_name>";

//credentials.json file
{
   "web":{
      "client_id":"<client_id>",
      "project_id":"<project_id>",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"<secret>",
      "redirect_uris":[
      "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly&access_type=offline",
         "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground",
         "http://localhost:8888/Callback"
      ]
   }
}
 
// getCredentials function that returns authorized credentials object    
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
            // Load client secrets.
            InputStream in = CalendarQuickStart.class.getResourceAsStream("/credentials.json");
            if (in == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
            }
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    
            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
            LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
            Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
            //returns an authorized Credential object.
            return credential;
        }

    //Gets credentials object from getCredentials and uses that to create calendar event

    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
            
            event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

Thanks.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] i would like to see the code you are using to authorize your applicaiton.

Comment: Thanks, I have now added requested sample code.

Comment: I thought you said you were using a service account thats not service account authorization code, Have you configured domain wide delegation to the service account though google workspace?

Comment: Domain wide delegation allows apps to access users' data across your organization's Google Workspace environment. I am developing an app for a non profit organization where team members have their own personal gmail accounts. Is there a way for the app to update users' meetings via service account authorization?

Comment: The only way to use google calendar with a service account is to use Google workspace domain accounts and configure delegation.  For normal Gmail user accounts, you will need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user once store the refresh token for later use.   In my answer see point number 3

Comment: Thanks, got it.

To summarize:
i) UserA is scheduling meeting with UserB and UserC
ii) Users A and B's calendars have manually provided permissions with access level 'Make changes to events' to my app's admin owner alias, so webapp have no issues creating events in their calendars
iii) User C has not yet given any such permission manually and hence gets 403 forbidden with message 'You need to have writer access to this calendar'.
I feel that providing permission to a gmail account vs an account that cannot login (such as service account) could be a concerning factor for users.

Comment: UserA schedules a meeting.   UserA creates an event and invites  user B and C to the event. User B and C will get a notification from google calendar to accept the invite.   You dont need B and C's permission to add them to an event.  Service accounts are only intended for user with calendars you the developer control.     Say a meeting room calendar.   Its not meant for you to use to get access to a standard gmail users account.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my comment that User A receives 403 (writer access error) only when scheduling meeting with B and C via the app. It all works after B and C gives write permission to the app owner. It’s not correct that recipients have to give permission to app owner manually for the app to be able to create meeting with them.

Comment: What scope did you request of User A? You only need write access to A to be able to create an event and invite other people.   You shouldn't be creating an even on B and C. You should be creating an event on A and inviting people to that.

Comment: Correct, I am creating credentials with scope 'CalendarScopes.CALENDAR' only for the User A in above scenario. But this needs to be done for any user attempting to create a meeting. So if User B wants to create a meeting, the app will create credentials with scope 'CalendarScopes.CALENDAR' for User B, which requires B to provide manual write/update access to the app owner so app can create event in B's calendar. Thus, any user that creates meeting via app needs to provide write access to the app owner. And not all users would be comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden means that the user you are authencation with does not have access to the data you are trying to request.

This is normally caused by one of three things.

1. You have not properly configured [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation)
2. You have continued it but have not added the subject domain user in your code.
3. Your trying to use it with a standard gmail google account, which does not support service accounts.